# How to insert date and time to DateTimeField in Django after a function in python script gets executed?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django Template that contains a text which says **"None"**. Besides the text, I want to display the time after a user clicks on a button.

Once clicked, a function will be called in the views.py module and calculates the current time. I want to store this time in the DateTimeField in my model and access the value in my Template. How can this be done?

This is what I had done so far:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Time(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  #I didn't use a auto_now = True parameter since I intend to add my own datetime only after a user clicks on the button.
```

code.py (external script):

```
from datetime import datetime

def time():
    current_time = datetime.now()
    date_time = current_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")  
    return date_time
```

Output of the above code:

```
'15/11/2019 16:10:39'
```

views.py:

```
from code import time  #accessing the code.py file since it is in root directory
from .models import Time

def current_time(request):
    c_time = time()
    #if the time is not available in DateTimeField(), then create it in the model.
    if not Time.objects.filter(time= c_time).exists(): 
        Time.objects.create(time= c_time)
    else:
        #If time already exists in model, then grab the user_id and replace the current index time with a new one using the update() method.
        Time.objects.filter(user_id=1).update(time= c_time) 
    context = {
        "data": Time.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html', context)
```

home.html:

```
{% for piece in data %}
    {% if piece.time %}
         <!-- If time exists, then place it near the text  -->
        <div class="placeRight">
            <p> Last indexed: 
                <b> {{piece.time}}</b> 
            </p> 
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <!-- If time doesnt exist in model, then just state "None"  -->
        <div class="placeRight">
            <p class="float-right"> Last indexed: 
                <b> None </b> 
            </p> 
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py:

```
from users import views as users_views
urlpatterns = [
    path('current_time/', users_views.current_time, name = 'current_time'),
]
```

After trying this, I got an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'15/11/2019 16:10:39' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH
:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

How can I add a custom date to my Django model and display its value in the Template?

Comment: Well, as the error states, you're using slashes rather than dashes in the date. But it's not clear what the point is of your `time()` function in the first place. Why do you think you need to convert to a string?  Why not just do `c_time = datetime.now()` in your view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman will datetime.now() work and be added to my DateTimeField()? Can I save this value via views.py module and access it in my Template? I am new to Django so am learning the process.

Comment: Yes of course. A DateTimeField, as its name implies, expects a datetime.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is the rest of the code correct? I mean, accessing the value in the template along with the for/if/else conditionals? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

my code looks like that

**html**

```
  {% for i in get_all%}
<h1>time befor formating</h1>
<h1>{{i.time}}</h1>
<h3>Time after formating</h3>
<h3>{{i.date_now}}</h3>
```

{% endfor %}

**model.py**

```
class Time(models.Model):
# user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
time = models.DateTimeField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def date_now(self):
    return self.time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
get_all = Time.objects.all()
context = {'get_all':get_all}
return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

**final result**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvNQU.png)

Comment: urls in project
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('newhelp.urls'))
]
urls in app
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]

Comment: Thank you SABRIO, I wil check this out. By the way, can you please explain why did you create a date_now method in the models.py module? What is the reason for it?

Comment: if you have body field "text"   and you want to show just summary like a few words you can add a function like that 
def summary(self):
return self .body[:100]#will return first 100 character 
__________
the point of date_now is to make life easy :D instead of doing complex models 
and it's function you can edit whatever you want .
_________
when you iterate over query_set Don't Forget forget to put it into html .
<h3>{{i.date_now}}</h3>